# LINQ query with Multiple Tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am joining the two tables using LINQ to match model class like below

[image]

```
    lstOptInInterest = new LinkedList<OptInInterestArea>
                       ((from a in dbEntities.SUBCODE
                       from appCode in dbEntities.CODE.Where(
                          x => x.CODE == a.CODE  && x.TYPE == a.TYPE)
                        select new OptInInterestArea()
                        {
                               Code = a.CODE,
                               SubCode = a.SUBCODE,
                               SubCodeDescription = a.DESCR,
                               CodeDescription = appCode.DESCR
                          }).ToList());
```

### Model class

```
public class OptInInterestArea
{      
        [DisplayName("Code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Sub Code")]
        public string SubCode { get; set; }

        DisplayName("Sub Code Description")]
        public string SubCodeDescription { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Code Description")]
        public string CodeDescription { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Previous OptIn")]
        public bool PrevOptIn { get; set; }
}
```

### Table B

[image]

Now my question is I need to assign `PrevOptIn` values of `lstOptInInterest`  from Table B (see above). Table B may or may not contains all of `CODE` and `SUBCODE` of `lstOptInInterest`.

If `CODE` and `SUBCODE` of `lstOptInInterest` exists on the table B assign to `PrevOptIn` in  else `PrevOptIn = N`

How can I do LINQ to get this?

Comment: I think you should LEFT OUT JOIN in LINQ to query A and B table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, I suggest you use `INNER JOIN` instead of `CROSS JOIN` to query your lstOptInInterest :

```
lstOptInInterest = new LinkedList<OptInInterestArea>
                       ((from a in dbEntities.SUBCODE
                         join appCode in dbEntities.CODE
                         on new {CODE=a.CODE,TYPE=a.TYPE} equals new {CODE=x.CODE,TYPE=x.TYPE}
                         select new OptInInterestArea()
                          {
                               Code = a.CODE,
                               SubCode = a.SUBCODE,
                               SubCodeDescription = a.DESCR,
                               CodeDescription = appCode.DESCR
                          }).ToList());
```

seconde, use `LEFT OUT JOIN` to assign PrevOptIn values of lstOptInInterest from Table B :

```
lstOptInInterest = new LinkedList<OptInInterestArea>
            (
                  (from a in lstOptInInterest
                          join b in dbEntities.TableB
                          on new {CODE=a.Code,SUBCODE=a.SubCode} equals new {CODE=b.CODE,SUBCODE=b.SUBCODE}
                          into leftGroup
                          from b in leftGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new OptInInterestArea()
                          {
                               Code = a.Code,
                               SubCode = a.SubCode,
                               SubCodeDescription = a.SubCodeDescription,
                               CodeDescription = a.CodeDescription,
                               PrevOptIn=b==null? false : b.OPTIN=="Y"
                          }).ToList()
            );
```

**UPDATE:**
Try to test this only 1 steps to get your result:

```
lstOptInInterest = new LinkedList<OptInInterestArea>
                       ((from a in dbEntities.SUBCODE
                         join appCode in dbEntities.CODE
                         on new {CODE=a.CODE,TYPE=a.TYPE} equals new {CODE=x.CODE,TYPE=x.TYPE}
                         join b in dbEntities.TableB
                         on new {CODE=a.CODE,SUBCODE=a.SUBCODE} equals new {CODE=b.CODE,SUBCODE=b.SUBCODE}
                         into leftGroup
                         from b in leftGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new OptInInterestArea()
                          {
                               Code = a.CODE,
                               SubCode = a.SUBCODE,
                               SubCodeDescription = a.DESCR,
                               CodeDescription = appCode.DESCR,
                               PrevOptIn=b==null?false : b.OPTIN=="Y"
                          }).ToList());
```